# Isomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2 +x +1)$ to the Eisenstein integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-isomorphism

I'm trying to work out a proof that the ring $R =\{a + b\omega : a, b \in \mathbb{Z} \}$, such that $\omega = (-1 + i\sqrt{3})/2$, is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2 +x +1)$. Constructing a homomorphism of the form $f:\mathbb{Z}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is supposed to aid me, but I'm really struggling to see why.

I'm guessing it's something to do with the isomorphism theorem and that $ker(f) = x^2 + x + 1$ is a requirement of the construction of the isomorphism $f$ but I'm just at a loss as to if this is correct and if so how to proceed.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: why not take $x$ to $\omega$?

Comment: Elaboration of the last comment: let $f: \mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{C}$ via $a_n x^n + \dots + a_1 x + a_0 \mapsto a_n \omega^n + \dots + a_1 \omega + a_0$. Does this help?

Comment: So by doing this, since we have $\omega^2 + \omega + 1 =0$ then that isomorphism will have the correct kernel? If so I get that, does that subsequently mean that the image of $f$ is $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2 + x + 1)$ by exchanging $\omega$ and $x$?

Comment: Note that if $(x-1)(x^2+x+1) = x^3-1$. Therefore $x^3-1 \in \ker(f)$. Therefore $f(x^3-1)=0$, so $f(x)^3-1=0$, so $f(x)^3=1$. That means $f(x)$ must be a cube root of unity (assuming $f : \mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{C}$ is a  homomorphism with $\ker(f) = ( x^2+x+1 )$). However $x-1$ by itself is *not* in the kernel of $f$, so $f(x-1) \neq 0$, so $f(x) \neq 1$. Therefore $f(x)$ must be a cube root of unity, other than $1$ (a "primitive" cube root of unity). The choices are $f(x) = \omega$ or $\overline{\omega}$. The point here is to narrow down possible homomorphisms $f$.

Comment: I follow that, but I'm struggling to understand where the intuition comes from for multiplying by $x-1$, is it just to prove that $f(x) \neq 1$?

Comment: @bcoscroft Replying to your $1^{\text{st}}$ comment: the image of $f \cong \mathbb{Z}[x] / \ker f$ by the $1^{\text{st}}$ isomorphism theorem.

Comment: Is there a way to prove the result without using that $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ is an Euclidean domain?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\phi: \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+x+1)\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ such that $\phi(a+bx)=a+b\omega$, where $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$

- This is a homomorphism since $$\phi(a+bx)\phi(a'+b'x)=(a+b\omega)(a'+b'\omega)=aa'-bb'+\omega(a'b+ab'-bb')=\phi\left (aa'-bb'+x(a'b+ab'-bb')\right )=\phi\left ((a+bx)(a'+b'x)\right)$$
  (I have used that $x^2=-x-1$) and $$\phi(a+bx)+\phi(a'+b'x)=(a+a')+\omega (b+b')=\phi\left ((a+a')+(b+b')x\right)$$
- If $\phi(a+bx)=a+b\omega=0$, then $a=b=0$ since $1,\omega$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Z}$. One way to see this is to assume that $a\neq 0$ and $b\neq 0$. Then $\left (\frac{a}{b}\right )^3=-1$. This is only possible if $b=-a$, so $a(1-\omega)=0$, but this is impossible! So $a=b=0$, and so $\ker(\phi)=0$
- $\phi$ is surjective since for any element $a+b\omega\in\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ we have $\phi(a+bx)=a+b\omega$